# how to define feature and class/target on knn

Tags: python, class, knn, feature-selection

I have a file named cars.xls. In the dataset, there are 6 columns, namely the name of the car, size, comfort, economy, speed, price. I am confused about which is the class/target in the dataset.

if I want to create a system to provide the best recommendations based on user input, is it enough to calculate the closest distance from user input data to train data.
if I want to do knn classification, what should I do?

This is describe of my data

```
          Size  | comfort   | economy   | speed |   price (in Million)

count : 17.000000 | 17.000000 | 17.000000 | 17.000000 | 17.000000

mean : 6.529412 | 6.352941 | 6.941176 | 6.823529 | 3.247059

std : 2.034627 | 2.234423 | 1.784327 | 1.131111 | 2.406597

min : 3.000000 | 3.000000 | 4.000000 | 5.000000 | 0.800000

25% : 5.000000 | 4.000000 | 6.000000 | 6.000000 | 1.750000

50% : 7.000000 | 7.000000 | 7.000000 | 7.000000 | 2.300000

75% : 8.000000 | 8.000000 | 9.000000 | 8.000000 | 5.000000

max : 10.000000 | 10.000000 | 10.000000 | 9.000000 | 10.000000
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you would not need to do a K-NN 'classification' but simply a 1-NN search: finding the closest vector to your user's query.

You need to find a good way to normalize your data to give each of the features a similar importance.

Take a look at sklearn's methods.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also think so, but I'm still confused whether the price includes features or class/target?

Comment: It depends what is your goal. If you simply want to select the best fit regarding the user's query, then the price is a feature like all other features. However, if you want to make some sort of price prediction, then price will become a target as in a regression model.

Comment: Okay, I see. But i still have confusion. It's about my data. I've added a describe of my data in the question. Is it still necessary to normalize ? I see the scale is right between 0-10

Comment: for me, it's always better to normalize and apply the same transformation to queries.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very useful